# FB Open graph: Possible to search object fields?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to search public objects by their fields? For example:

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&fields=venue](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&fields=venue&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000)

Will get me all events matching conference and show their locations. Is there a way to filter for events in San Francisco?

I've tried something like:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&fields=venue&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also checked this. There is no any way to search in fields. **only event search will work for TITLE of events only by Facebook** *and not in description also*. There is get url by latitude longitude but this also not working from fb. i dont know when they will solve this issues.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&fields=venue&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000